# why does it work with sed -e but not with sed -i

Tags: bash, sed

I have this in a file

```
echo "[[z[z[[e" > toto_test.txt
```

i'm trying this and things are ok

```
sed -e 's,\],,g' -e 's,\[,,g' toto_test.txt
```

Doing this and suddenly, it is not working anymore

```
sed -i 's,\],,g' -i 's,\[,,g' toto_test.txt
```

I have this error

```
sed: impossible to read s,\[,,g: No such file or directory
```

Why and how can I overcome the thing?

Thanks.

Comment: `-i` is a parameter supposed to be given once. By using it twice `sed` gets "confused".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
sed -i -e 's,\],,g' -e 's,\[,,g' toto_test.txt
```

`-i` means inplace modification,

`-e` means expression.

once you understand this, it's easy to provide proper parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 replacements. Just use it as:

```
sed -i.bak 's,[][],,g' toto_test.txt
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, why have twice the bracket?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, forgot that exception.

Comment: This is not twice the bracket actually. Anything within `[` and `]` is called character class and inner `]` and `[` are actually part of the character class.

Comment: smart, @anubhava, smart. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so far as I know, -i can't be repeated.  It expect an optional backup suffix for the file edited in place (mandatory on OS X).

Try

```
sed -i 's,\],,g; s,\[,,g' toto_test.txt
```

(wanted to make this a comment but I don't seem to be allowed to do so, so I made it an answer)